# KSQLDB - Materializing a view from a Table used a lot of SPACE

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

I have created a materializing a view from Table - Table Join. During operation, a lot of capacity is generated in the system but it are  non-windowed joins according to KSQLDB document.
The ultimate goal of joining these two tables is to retrieve a single topic for another system of mine. Therefore, materializing a view from Table - Table Join is short-term. Is there a way to limit this viewing mode?

Is there a way to limit this viewing mode?